# Connect adress book and Outlook online (Office 365)

Tags: office-365, outlook

I have an address book in SharePoint and would like to use the data in Outlook (Office 365 online).

For example there is the entry
Name: Test name
E-mail: testname@test.com

and I want Outlook to suggest the e-mail address stored in the address book when I enter "testna".

How do I connect the address book and Outlook in this case? Is there a possibility that this connection will be established for all accounts of my organization?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online is the wrong tool for this. You need to make contact objects in Exchange Online.

Comment: Is there a way to manage my contacts stored in Exchange through SharePoint?

Comment: Nothing out of the box.